# Chrome linear gradient bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, gradient

I have a repeating linear gradient like so:

```
.placeholder { 
background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top right, #7722AA 0px, #7722AA 6%, #CC44EE 6%, #CC44EE 13%) transparent;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float: left;
height: 110px;
width: 120px;
}
```

However in chrome, firefox on Mac and opera the appearance is skewed: [image]

It works fine when in a square, but when it becomes a rectangle it becomes jagged - the same doesn't occur in all other browsers.

What causes this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2KsQ/1/)

Comment: That's just the way it is rendered...

Comment: @Xarcell... so? Doesn't mean it's rendered correctly...

Comment: what I mean is, that's the best Chrome can do at this point. Your just not gonna get non-jagged lines at that angle. Adjust the angle or do what Blazemonger says, add a little blur...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
.placeholder { 
background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #7722AA 0px, #7722AA 6%, #CC44EE 6%, #CC44EE 13%) transparent;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float: left;
height: 110px;
width: 120px;
}
```

?

Comment: Since your box is rectangular and not square, the angle from the top right to the bottom edge isn't 45 degrees.  Depending on the drawing library used by the browser, having angles that aren't in multiples of 45 degrees are likely to be blurry.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to spread out your gradient a bit more. Adding a 2% gradient transition to either side of the stripe gives a slight blur that obscures the jaggies without eliminating the edge.

```
repeating-linear-gradient(to top right, #CC44EE 0px, #7722AA 2%, #7722AA 7%, #CC44EE 9%, #CC44EE 14%) transparent
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FrT6Y/

To increase the blur along the stripe edge, increase the 2% to 3% or more and then decrease the 7% to 6% or more to keep the stripes the same size:

```
repeating-linear-gradient(to top right, #CC44EE 0px, #7722AA 3%, #7722AA 6%, #CC44EE 9%, #CC44EE 14%) transparent
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FrT6Y/5/

Comment: Unfortunately my desired output is how the original code is rendered in FF, IE and Presto, which is correct

Comment: Might be worth a [bug report](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-bugs), then. Although Firefox for Mac gives me the same jaggies.

Comment: Just seen the same issue occurs on Opera on Win8 - maybe it's desired?