# css striped bg oddities in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having issues getting an angled stripe background to show nicely in Chrome.

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 1px, transparent 0px, transparent 4px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hornetnz/JxvNd/

It seems to show in Firefox and IE10 fine. But Chrome develops a pattern gap every few lines.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%);
background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%);
background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%);

-webkit-background-size: 4px 4px;
   -moz-background-size: 4px 4px;
     -o-background-size: 4px 4px;
        background-size: 4px 4px;

/* Background size must be an even number! */
```

Here's your updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/JxvNd/1/

Comment: This doesn't work on Safari 8, Mac or Windows. The stripes are all messed up :  [Stripes not working on Safari](http://i.snag.gy/jna7K.jpg)

Comment: I ended up using SVG and creating a little SASS mixin to do that - set the svg has background and color it -  http://codepen.io/gfra/pen/vOoErq (this is not the same 1px stripes, but you just have to make a new svg stripe pattern)

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be chrome rendering bug as answered here: [Chrome linear gradient bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694669/chrome-linear-gradient-bug)

You could try some of these alternatives:

1. Use blur edge transition like described in above link
2. Use svg (looks like this is the pattern you want: http://www.svgeneration.com/generate/Diagonal-Stripes)
3. Try using regular linear-gradient and combining it with background size (not sure if it's possible to get repeating background that way. I will try and make pen later)