# CSS Stripes Not Displaying Correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I have a website in which I'm trying to get a background of subtle pinstripes using two gradients. I achieved that using this CSS:

```
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 2px,
        #101010 4px,
        #737373 4px 
       ),
        repeating-radial-gradient(
        #616161,
        #222222 
        );
```

In Firefox, the stripes look great, but when I take it into Chrome, it looks horrible.

If you open this link in Chrome, you should be able to see what I mean.

[JS Fiddle - Not appearing correctly in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/bnies813/smt3uuv8/)

I've tried finding a solution online and the closest I've come is this post:

[css striped bg oddities in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429995/css-striped-bg-oddities-in-chrome)

I applied the code from the above post, into my CSS, adding in the radial gradient. Here's my JS Fiddle to show my result.

[JS Fiddle - Strange Checkerboard](http://jsfiddle.net/bnies813/9nx611xc/)

When I apply it, as you'll see, or have seen, I get a strange checkerboard pattern. How can I get an angled, linear gradient on top, a radial gradient on the bottom and have them appear correctly in all browsers?

I even tried combining the CSS I stared with, with the "webkit" block and that didn't work at all:

```
    html {
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%), repeating-radial-gradient(#616161, #222222);
background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%, repeating-radial-gradient(#616161, #222222);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%), repeating-radial-gradient(#616161, #222222);
background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%), repeating-radial-gradient(#616161, #222222);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%, repeating-radial-gradient(#616161, #222222);

-webkit-background-size: 4px 4px;
-moz-background-size: 4px 4px;
-o-background-size: 4px 4px;
background-size: 4px 4px; 
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I have searched for hours, tried many things...and cannot get this work!

Comment: So, you need the same what I can see in other browsers except Chrome like in first [variant](http://jsfiddle.net/bnies813/smt3uuv8)?

Comment: I'm seeing checker box tearing in Firefox, but it looks alright in Chrome.

Comment: As a note to the person who comes up with the solution, I opened the fiddle link, and it looks great for me in chrome but worse in firefox, the exact opposite of the the OP is describing, I look forward to the answer here.

Comment: AleshaOleg - I'm looking for a resizeable pinstripe pattern, with a radial gradient effect. I'm trying to get it to look clean in all browsers. On my computer, it's not appearing clean in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```
   background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(
   45deg, transparent, transparent 2px, #101010 4px, #737373 4px
   ),
   -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(#616161, #222222); background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 2px,
    #101010 4px,
    #737373 4px 
   ),
    repeating-radial-gradient(
    #616161,
    #222222 
    );
```

Try This on .

And Recommend a very useful site [prefix your css](http://pleeease.io/play/)

And [the compatibility of browsers](http://caniuse.com)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, but those links seems like they are going to be very helpful/useful. Thank you!